# Django: unable to use related_name to fetch username from User class

Tags: python, django

I need to get the starter full name in a query. I have written the following query in shell and it is giving an error.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='topics')
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete = models.CASCADE,  related_name='topics')
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

print(Topic.objects.all().values('board__description','subject','user__username'))
```

The error is : `Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field`.

Please could you help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have no field named `user` in your model. It should be `starter`.

```
print(Topic.objects.all().values('board__description', 'subject', 'starter__username'))
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you for your help Mr. Khairul Basar

Comment: @Surej Welcome. Have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).